# Is there any setting in Vim that let cmdline be on top of statusline?

Tags: vim

I want to exchange the position of cmdline and statusline, and let cmdline automatically disappear when I quit command-line mode. Is it possible? How to do it?

Comment: I'm just curious, why would you want that?

Comment: @sica07 Instead of command line, statusline should always show itself on the bottom. And when you're not in the command-line mode, the command line is totally useless, it shoudn't occupy the room permanently. Last but not least, the blank line at the bottom makes me feel anxious.

Comment: @Vayn - Drink some tea. That will take care of the anxiety. As for the cmdline, there is nothing you can do.

Comment: @ldigas It seems I need a patch for this purpose. Anyway, thank you. :)

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no such setting.

You can modify the appearance of statusline and its appearance with `statusline` and `laststatus` but the command line stays where it is - on the bottom. Btw, this is a relatively often asked for feature (there should be already a few similar questions on this site), but I don't know of any patches that touch that behaviour.